# How to write an Add-In for MonoDevelop (2.8+)?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, monodevelop

I'm trying to write an add-in for MonoDevelop 2.8 (Mac Version). Unfortunately, I'm unable to do so because the Add-In manager does not seem to recognize the compiled add-in library.

I tried [the user guide](http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Articles/Addin_development_basics) on MonoDevelop website, but I suspect it's outdated and I wasn't able to find more information on the topic.

Does anyone know how to write add-ins for new versions of MonoDevelop?

Comment: http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Articles/Addin_development_basics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also try the other guide to [creating a simple addin](http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Articles/Creating_a_Simple_Add-in).

Obviously you'll have to update the version numbers of the dependencies. You should also be aware that the addin directory changed - see the article on [user profiles](http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Articles/User_Profiles). I don't think anything else changed.

That said, rather than copying the addin into the addin install directory at dev time, I would now use `MONODEVELOP_DEV_ADDINS` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637994/how-can-i-debug-monodevelop-add-ins-with-monodevelop/9642405#9642405).

Comment: Oooh! I'll use MONODEVELOP_DEV_ADDINS here for my perforce addin!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll check and let you know here

Comment: Figured out what was wrong, the addin directory (at least for MacOSX) is not the one that is indicated in this article. On my machine it was /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/Addins. Otherwise the user guide works.

Comment: Don't install addins directly into the app bundle, they'll be removed when MD is updated. I'm pretty sure the directory the builds points to is correct (though you'll have to update the "2.8" value to "3.0" for MD 3.0). But you could check by installing a new addin from the addin manager and finding out where it puts the addin.

Comment: @Kel: On my machine it seems to be `/Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/Addins` instead.